# How to mmap kernel memory area to userspace?

Tags: kernel, mmap

I want to mmap a kernel memory area which sk_buf->data pointer into userspace. I want to do this , because this way can reduce a copy from kernel to userspace.
      How to fix it? Or, which book or project can help me ?

Thank you.